# How to submit ionic form with the ion-footer submit button? I am trying this http://play.ionic.io/app/07e251b1e926

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I have a FORM inside Ion-content and I want to submit that FORM from the button placed inside Ion-footer with all the form validations.  Structure of the code at http://play.ionic.io/app/07e251b1e926,

But It is not triggering submit event.Anyone has done this?

Answer (score 4):

Try this, Add label outside form as button and add hidden button inside form also.

```
<form name="myform" ng-submit="submitmyform()" >
        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" style="display:none"/>
```

then footer label give `for` attribute set the`button` id in the form

```
<a href="#"><label style="width:100%;heigh:30px;background-color:red" for="submit">Submit</label></a>
```

Also Should include controller [`formController`] outside form also.

http://play.ionic.io/app/0e22c14ea697

Answer (score 3):

Using the latest version of Ionic ion-footer you need to add your form again within the footer tags. Footer should be after ion-content close. I did this and now my form can scroll behind the footer and has an extra item-worth of padding at the bottom!

```html
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>New Project</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <form [formGroup]="newProjectForm" (submit)="addProject()" novalidate>
 <ion-list>
   <ion-item>
     <ion-label color="primary" stacked>Project Title</ion-label>
     <ion-input formControlName="title" clearInput></ion-input>
   </ion-item>
 </ion-list>
  </form>
</ion-content>

<ion-footer>
  <form [formGroup]="newProjectForm" (submit)="addProject()" novalidate>
 <ion-toolbar>
   <button ion-button block color="green" type="submit">
     Save
   </button>
 </ion-toolbar>
  </form>
</ion-footer>
```

Answer (score 3):

This is what helped me on ionic 3, FormBuilder with validation.

```
<ion-content padding>
  <form (ngSubmit)="login()" #loginForm="ngForm">
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label floating>Email</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="form.email" name="email"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label floating>Password</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="password" [(ngModel)]="form.password" name="password"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </form>
</ion-content>

<ion-footer>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <button ion-button block full large clear [disabled]="!loginForm.form.valid" (click)="loginForm.ngSubmit.emit()">Login</button>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-footer>
```

Comment: Just wanna add that this method is also working in Ionic 4

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code in ionic2:

```
<ion-content>
  <form (ngSubmit)="login()" #loginForm="ngForm">
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Email</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="form.email" name="email"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Password</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="password" [(ngModel)]="form.password" name="password"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </form>
</ion-content>

<ion-footer>
    <button ion-button full (click)="loginForm.ngSubmit.emit()">Login</button>
</ion-footer>
```

Comment: Just wanna add that in Ionic 4, this is also working.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is a better alternative if you are using FormBuilder instead of ngModel.

Put this code after the form crated in your .ts file.

```
this.signForm.statusChanges
        .subscribe(status => this.formIsValid = status);
```

In the .html file you can check if the form is valid like this.

```
<button ion-button round large color="secondary" float-right [disabled]="!formIsValid" (click)="onSubmit()">Save</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know is old question, but the best way i see:

```
<div>
  <form id="my-form">
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="name"></input>
  </form>

  <!-- ... -->

  <button type="submit" form="my-form">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Note that `form` is a HTML5 attribute.